# UML library for .NET

Tags: .net, uml, object-model

I'm looking for a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) class library to load UML models (the more serialization formats the better) for an application I'm developing. I only need the UML object model, no graphs, graphic, UI or anything like that.

Currently, I'm using [NUml](http://numl.sourceforge.net/). However, it hasn't seen much maintainance in the last few years and is somewhat outdated.

The library should be fully managed, bonus points if open source (but not neccessary). I've looked in the open source space already and couldn't really come up with **anything**.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I see what you mean about nUml; being a little out-dated.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found meanwhile would be to use [IKVM.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKVM.NET) to cross compile one of the available Java libraries to a .NET library.

However, while this approach works, it is quite ugly as my interest lies in the UML object model and in the case I will have a library following Java style guidelines mixed with my C# code following .NET style guidelines (most visible in all method names being lowercase and not using properties although an UML object model would basically be ONLY properties).

So if anybody comes up with something better I'm still interested.